# SBT Migration: How to replace Command.process

Tags: sbt

I have a statement in my 0.13x build.sbt file that composes a sbt.Command with the onLoad function:

```
onLoad in Global := (Command.process("project server", _: State)) compose (onLoad in Global).value
```

Now when updating to SBT 1.1.0 the Command.process method does not exist anymore, neither exists a method with the same signature. So how can I achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onLoad in Global := (onLoad in Global).value andThen ("project server" :: _)
```

or if you fancy the even terser:

```
onLoad in Global ~= (_ andThen ("project server" :: _))
```

Answer (score 1):

Command.process was moved to MainLoop.processCommand

[API reference - MainLoop.processCommand](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.1.0/api/sbt/MainLoop$.html#processCommand(exec:sbt.Exec,state:sbt.State):sbt.State)

You migrate to as below.

`onLoad in Global := (MainLoop.processCommand(Exec("project server", None), _: State)) compose (onLoad in Global).value`